# How to change two duplicate words into non duplicate line using shell

Tags: perl, shell

I have One file Inside which I have a naming convention as

```
         .
         .
         .
delay_rise = 20ps
delay_rise = 40ps
         .
         .
         .
```

I need to change 2nd delay_rise into delay_fall. How can I do it?

Comment: Will there be multiple instances of this throughout the file, i.e. pairs of `delay_rise` where the second item in each pair needs to be changed, or is this a one-time-per-file sort of thing?

Comment: its one time per file

Comment: arpan, please provide clarification [within your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32282392/edit), along with your attempt so far. The code I provided in my answer below certainly addressed the limited scope of your question. If you post your own attempt, I'd be happy to address any problems I see in it.

Comment: Actually, I have multiple files in which I need to change this. So, what I did was, i used foreach and awk for changing the files ----- foreach a (`cat list`)    awk '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' $a >> $a end    But seems its entering into some infinite loop. So, I want to redirect my changes to the same file using awk. How can I do it?

Comment: arpan, don't put that in a comment. Comments have terrible formatting. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' file
         .
         .
         .
delay_rise = 20ps
delay_fall = 40ps
         .
         .
         .
```

This works by setting a counter `f` for the number of times that we have seen a line that contains `delay_rise`.  If and only if we are on the second occurrence, `f==2`, then we substitute in `delay_fall`.

The `1` at the end of the script is awk's cryptic notation for print-this-line.

#### Changing multiple files in place

If you have a recent version of GNU awk, just list all the files on the command line and use the `-i inplace` option:

```
awk -i inplace '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' file*
```

If you have a BSD awk or older GNU awk, then use:

```
for f in file*; do awk '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' "$f" >tmp.out && mv tmp.out "$f"; done
```

If you prefer your commands spread out over multiple lines, then the same command can be run as:

```
for f in file*
do
    awk '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' "$f" >tmp.out && mv tmp.out "$f"
done
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to do it in multiple files using foreach. So, what I did was foreach a (`cat files`)                       awk '/delay_rise/ {f++; if (f==2) sub(/delay_rise/, "delay_fall")} 1' $a >> $a end.  But somehow its entering in some infinite loop. Can you please tell me, if I want to update in multiple files using awk, and want to keep the file name also same, what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways you can do this in shell.

This should work in any POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

flag=0
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    delay_rise*)
      if [ "$flag" -eq 0 ]; then
        flag=1
      else
        line="delay_fall${line#delay_rise}"
        flag=0
      fi
      ;;
  esac
  echo "$line"
done
```

Note that the `flag=0` within the `if` statement allows you to use this to handle multiple "pairs" within a file. It's a state change, and it toggles.

Another alternative would be awk. John's awk solution is excellent, but there are many ways to achieve any task. Mine would be similar to his, though a little more brief:

```
awk '/^delay_rise/&&f{sub(/rise/,"fall")} /^delay_rise/{f=1} 1' file
```

This works by treating `f` as a semaphore rather than a counter.  But again, if you needed to handle multiple pairs per file, resetting the semaphore would require a minor addition:

```
awk '/^delay_rise/&&f{sub(/rise/,"fall");f=0;print;next} /^delay_rise/{f=1} 1' file
```

Split out for easier reading, this would look like:

```
awk '
  # If we find our text AND the flag is set...
  /^delay_rise/ && f {
    sub(/rise/,"fall");  # replace text
    f=0;                 # reset semaphore
    print;               # print the line, and
    next;                # move on to the next line.
  }

  # If this is an interesting line and the semaphore was NOT set...
  /^delay_rise/ {
    # set it!
    f=1;
  }

  # Print whatever we've got.
  1
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach will be to just set a counter and check whether it is 2(for second occurence) and substitute there. A Perl script which will do similar thing is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $i=0;
while(<>){
       if(/delay_rise/)
        {
          ++$i;
          if($i==2)
           {
             s/delay_rise/delay_fall/;
           }
        }
print $_;
}
```